# Why are my p-values for lognormal distribution mean not uniform?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, t-test, p-value

I was wondering why my p-values for lognormal distribution are not uniform while using t-test for mean. Here is my code:

```r
set.seed(1234)
sims <- 5000
pvals <- vector(length=sims)

for(i in 1:sims){
  dist <- rlnorm(30)
  pvals[i] <- t.test(dist, mu=exp(0.5))$p.value
}

pvals %>% hist
```

The p-values look right-skewed but the lognormal distributions I generated should have mean = exp(0.5) based on the input parameters right? So then the null hypothesis is true so the p-values should be uniform. I'm not sure what I did wrong here.

Comment: what makes you think they should be normal?

Comment: @utobi I am thinking it is because it may be that the normality assumption of the t-test fails, but when I use the non-parametric Wilcox signed-rank test for true location it is also skewed with lots of small p-values (rejecting null indicating the true median is not the parameter median generated exp(0)).

Comment: With a known median, the signed-rank Wilcoxon test you performed might better be considered the following, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test#One-sample_test): "If the population median is known, then it can be used to test whether data is symmetric about its center." It's not, for a log-normal distribution.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test#One-sample_test): "The one-sample Wilcoxon signed-rank test can be used to test whether data comes from a _symmetric population_ with a specified median." (Emphasis added.) A log-normal distribution doesn't meet that Wilcoxon-test assumption of a symmetric population, just as the distribution of sample means (at a sample size of only 30) doesn't meet the t-test assumption of a normal distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the null hypothesis is true so the p-values should be uniform. I'm not sure what I did wrong here.

That would only be the case if the assumptions of the test were met. For a one-sample t-test, [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#One-sample_t-test): "Although the parent population does not need to be normally distributed, the distribution of the population of sample means $\bar {x}$ is assumed to be normal."

The following modification of your code shows the problem:

```
set.seed(1234)
sims<-5000
means<-vector(length=sims)
for(i in 1:sims){
   dist<-rlnorm(30);
   means[i]<-mean(dist)}
plot(density(means),bty="n",main="")
```

[image: distribution of mean values]

With this sample size, you have substantial skew in the distribution of sample means. So the t-test assumption of a normal distribution of sample means isn't met. The [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) doesn't come to the rescue in this case until you have larger sample sizes. Play with the sample size to investigate further.

*In response to comment*

The above was just intended to suggest that if the assumptions of a test aren't met then you shouldn't be surprised if you don't get proper coverage. Glen_b rightly notes in comments that the specific answer to the question is contained in the distribution of t-statistics. Here it is:

[image: distribution of t-values]

Again, large skew with nearly 12% of observed t-statistics outside the 95% CI, mostly on the left tail (584 below qt(0.025,29), 11 above qt(0.975,29)). Admittedly, one shouldn't put too much weight on a single simulation like this. I haven't thought through a theoretical basis for the sampling distribution of t-statistics with a lognormal distribution, although I suspect there's one somewhere in the literature.

The code:

```
set.seed(1234)
sims<-5000
tvals<-vector(length=sims)
for(i in 1:sims){
  dist<-rlnorm(30);
  tvals[i]<-(mean(dist)-exp(0.5))/(sd(dist)/sqrt(30))
}

plot(density(tvals),bty="n",ylim=c(0,0.4),xlim=c(-5,3),main="t-value distribution")
curve(dt(x,df=29),from=-5,to=3,col="red",add=TRUE)
abline(v=c(qt(0.025,29),qt(0.975,29)),lty=2,col="red")
legend("topleft",bty="n",legend="black, observed\nred, theoretical\ndashed, 95% limits")

sum(tvals<qt(0.025,29))
# [1] 584
sum(tvals>qt(0.975,29))
# [1] 11
```

Comment: +1 but ... With a t-test note that the test statistic is not $\bar{X}$. The denominator is also a random variable and the test statistic is a ratio of two random variables (which are also not independent *unless* the parent distribution is normal). As a result it's not sufficient to simply consider the distribution of $\bar{X}$, one must consider the distribution of the statistic itself, and consider how close it is to being t-distributed rather than just how normal $\bar{X}$ is. While the distribution of  $\bar{X}$ provides some useful motivation in this situation, it's not quite dispositive.

Comment: An alternative would be to demonstrate that the distribution of $\bar{X}$ is overwhelmingly the driver of the shape of the distribution of $p$ rather than any effect of the denominator (and their joint dependence). This might be possible, but I haven't seen it done.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for the comments. My initial answer was just intended to point out that you can't count on results from a test when the underlying assumptions aren't strictly met. I added a plot of the distribution of t-statistics for this example.